Can rename(AS) a column/field from SELECT using APIv4
I want to rename the column/fields I am retreiving in the SELECT statement. Best way to ask this is by showing an example...
Given this select call:
$contacts = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'get', [
  'select' => [ 'id', 'display_name', ],
  'limit' => 5,
  'checkPermissions' => TRUE,
]);

Which returns object with:
[{"id": 2983,"display_name": null },]

But what if I want to rename the 'display_name' field as something else (say 'dname'), to get a result like this:
[{"id": 2983,"dname": null },]

I tried both the following but it does not work:
  'select' => [ 'id', 'display_name AS dname', ],
  'select' => [ 'id', 'display_name as dname', ],

Is there a way to do this, or is it not possible with the API call?
Thanks

There was a long discussion about this at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3738
which resulted in a new $result->rekey() method added to the next beta (5.74).
See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29714

Okay so that at least answers my question: "No you can not do that (yet)"!
